# Setting Different Email as Default Email w/ Powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook

I'm in the process of creating a script that will look in a users email account to find an email, then download an attachment from the email.

This automatically selects the users default email account as it is written. However, I have a second email account in Outlook that I want to use instead.

Is there any way to change which email account it searches?

```
$outlook = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
$namespace = $outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

#Below: 6 is the default for inbox, so this saves the user from having to select the inbox folder. Change if emails w/ attatchements are going to a different folder. 
$folder = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder(6)
$filepath = "C:\Users\Documents\PowerShell"

$folder.Items | foreach {
    $_.attachments | foreach {
        $filename = $_.filename
        If ($filename.Contains("example1.xls")) {
            $_.saveasfile((Join-Path $filepath $filename))
            Rename-Item -LiteralPath '.\example1.xls' -NewName "Server.xls"
        }

        If ($filename.Contains("example2.xls")) {
            $_.saveasfile((Join-Path $filepath $filename))
            Rename-Item -LiteralPath '.\example2.xls' -NewName "Workstation.xls"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like what you're trying to do is change the folder you're scanning? if so you'd need to change `$folder = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder(6)`

Comment: If manual intervention is appropriate, you could also do `$folder = $namespace.PickFolder()` to open Outlook's "Select Folder" gui which would assign the selected folder to the $folder variable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$namespace.GetDefaultFolder(6)`, find the appropriate Store object from the `Namespace.Stores` collection and call `Store.GetDefaultFolder`.

If the other mailbox is not in the `Namespace.Stores` collection, call `Namespace.CreateRecipient` / `Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder` instead.